# Can I show the Alert on HTML component?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4, flex3

I want to show PDF in Flex AIR.  I have done this with HTML components but the problem is that whenever I view the PDF in Flex HTML component the popup or Alert goes behind the component.

Please tell me how can I show the Alert on HTML component?

Comment: I ve just do this issue. but I got alert box correctly.

Comment: Also which flex/air sdk are you using ? if I am not wrong this was an known issue in earlier versions of air.

Answer (score 0):

You can display javascript alert box, it will display over the PDF.Please try this solution

htmlcomponehtmlLoader.window.alert('Please collect your print out from Reception.');